# Why will this sql cause type conversion error?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
WITH tb_testl AS （
    SELECT 1 AS id ,'hehe' AS value 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 AS id, '1' AS value 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2 AS id, '2' AS value 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2 AS id, '2' AS value
), tb_test2 AS (
    SELECT CONVERT(INT , value) AS value FROM tb_testl WHERE id = 2 
)
SELECT * FROM tb_test2 WHERE value = 2;
```

this sql will cause error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'hehe' to data
>   type int.

but the table `tb_test2` dosen't have the value 'hehe' which is in the anthor table `tb_test1`. And I found that this sql will work well if I don't append the statement `WHERE value = 2;` .I've tried `ISNUMBERIC` function but it didn't work.

version:mssql2008 R2

Comment: your `value` is string like `hehe`. In the second cte `tb_test2` you are trying to convert that (value in string) to `integer`, that's where it failed

Comment: By the way, you may want to consider upgrading to a more recent version of sql server; 2008 R2 will be unsupported by July 2019.

Comment: I got a response from official community which 
suggest me to use a temporary table rather than CTE.https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e8a4324f-9365-4123-8b05-61acac849ec4/318672241136716254423838239064

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With respect to the why this occurs:

There is a [Logical Processing Order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement), which describes the order in which clauses are evaluated. The order is:

```
FROM
ON
JOIN
WHERE
GROUP BY
WITH CUBE or WITH ROLLUP
HAVING
SELECT
DISTINCT
ORDER BY
TOP
```

You can also see the processing order when you `SET SHOWPLAN_ALL ON`. For this query, the processing is as follows:

1. Constant scan - this is the `FROM` clause, which consists of hard coded values, hence the constants.
2. Filter - this is the `WHERE` clause. While it looks like there are two where clauses (`WHERE id = 2` and `WHERE value = 2`). SQL Server sees this differently, it considers a single `WHERE` clause: `WHERE CONVERT(INT , value) = 2 AND id = 2`.
3. Compute scaler. This is the `CONVERT` function in the select.

Because both `WHERE` clauses are executed simultaneously, the `hehe` value is not filtered out of the `CONVERT` scope.

Effectively, the query is simplified to something like:

```
SELECT  CONVERT(INT, tb_testl.value) AS Cvalue
FROM    (
            SELECT  1 AS id
            ,       'hehe' AS value
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  1 AS id
            ,       '1' AS value
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  2 AS id
            ,       '2' AS value
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  2 AS id
            ,       '2' AS value
        ) tb_testl
WHERE   CONVERT(INT, tb_testl.value) = 2
    AND tb_testl.id = 2
```

Which should clarify why the error occurs.

With SQL, you cannot read code in the same way as imperative languages like C. Lines of SQL code are not necessarily (mostly not at all, in fact) executed in the same order it is written in. In this case, it's an error to think the inner where is executed *before* the outer where.

Comment: Thanks.It helped me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server does not guarantee the order of processing of statements (with one exception below).  That is, there is no guarantee that `WHERE` filtering happens before the `SELECT`.  Or that one CTE is evaluated before another.  This is considered an *advantage* because it allows SQL Server to rearrange the processing to optimize performance (although I consider the issue that you are seeing a bug).

Obviously, the problem is in this part of the code:

```
tb_test2 AS (
    SELECT CONVERT(INT, value) AS value
    FROM tb_testl
    WHERE id = 2 
)
```

(Well, actually, it is where `tb_test2` is referenced.)

What is happening is that SQL Server pushes the `CONVERT()` to where the values are being read, so the conversion is attempted *before* the `WHERE` clause is processed.  Hence, the error.

In SQL Server 2012+, you can easily solve this using `TRY_CNVERT()`:

```
tb_test2 AS (
    SELECT TRY_CONVERT(INT, value) AS value
    FROM tb_testl
    WHERE id = 2 
)
```

However, that doesn't work in SQL Server 2008.  You can use the fact that `CASE` does have some guarantees on the order of processing:

```
tb_test2 AS (
    SELECT (CASE WHEN value NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' THEN CONVERT(INT, value)
            END) AS value
    FROM tb_testl
    WHERE id = 2 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

error caused by this part of statement

```
), tb_test2 AS (
    SELECT CONVERT(INT , value) AS value FROM tb_testl WHERE id = 2
```

**value** has type of **varchar** and 'hehe' value cannot be converted to integer

```
WITH tb_testl AS （
   SELECT 1 AS id ,'hehe' AS value
```

**UPDATE:** sql try convert all value(s) to integer in you statement. to avoid error rewrite statement as

```
WITH tb_testl AS (
 SELECT 1 AS id ,'hehe' AS value 
 UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS id, '1' AS value 
 UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS id, '2' AS value 
 UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS id, '2' AS value
), tb_test2 AS (
 SELECT value AS value FROM tb_testl WHERE id = 2 
),
 tb_test3 AS (
 SELECT cast(value as int) AS value FROM tb_test2
)
SELECT * FROM tb_test3
```

Comment: I think the question is why is sql server attempting to convert `'hehe'` to an `int` when for `id = 2` there is only `value='2'`.

Comment: @HoneyBadger thank you. I think it because SQL Server perform data scan, value conversion and filtering simultaneously.

Comment: i tried but it will still cause error if you append the statement "WHERE value = 2" after

Comment: I think in this case sql server optimizer simplify query execution plan and ejects previous filtering in tb_test2